# assemble.io inlining js file

Tags: javascript, helper, assemble

is there an easy way to inline files with assemble.io?

i found only this one http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-code.html
but this replaces all " with &#x2 7; and at the first and last line it inserts &#x60 ;&#x60 ;&#x60 ;js

```
{{embed 'src/js/loadJs.js'}}
```

results in

```
&#x60;&#x60;&#x60;js
...
function load(scripts){
    ...
    script = document.createElement(&#x27;script&#x27;);
    ...
}
&#x60;&#x60;&#x60;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `embed` helper wraps the file content in ```` ``` ```` so it can be used in code examples.

If you know that you're going to use the helper specifically for embedding javascript like in your example. I would create a new helper that just reads the content in:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function inline(src) {
  return fs.readFileSync(src, 'utf8');
}
```

You can add some error handling and checking around that, but it'll inline the file for you.

You can either use `Handlebars.SafeString` around the content to indicate that the string should not be escaped, or you can use triple curly braces in the handlebars file: `{{{inline "path/to/file.js"}}}`

Comment: hi thank you ;) this looks much shorter than "my" approach i copied some codelines from there (https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers/blob/master/lib/utils/glob.js) to get my helper run as expected. but thanks for your answer, now i know there is a fs in node.js ;)